# spring - java interface default method overriden is avoided

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have below the interface

```
public interface MyInterface<T, H extends Serializable, R extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
  default List<T> findAll(H key) {
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
  }
}
```

The implementation is below,

```
public class RepositoryImpl<T, H extends Serializable, R extends Serializable>
    extends ACConcreateClassWhichImplementRepository<T, H> implements MyInterface<T, H, R> {
  @Override
  public List<T> findAll(H key) {
    return findSome(hashKey); //some method
  }
}
```

Upon calling this through the controller, the call is hitting the default method defined in MyInterface, instead of hitting the implementation in RepositoryImpl.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at com.MyInterface.findAll(MyInterface.java:12)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH.1294483354.invokeSpecialIFC(LambdaForm$DMH:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH.995808242.invoke(LambdaForm$MH:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH.1531802663.invoke(LambdaForm$MH:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.invokeExact_MT(Invokers$Holder:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
      at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:86)
      
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
      at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.findAll(Unknown Source:-1)
```

instead of default method if i define an abstract method in interface, then it hit on the implementation.

```
at com.RepositoryImpl.findAll(RepositoryImpl.java:16)
      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker$$Lambda$1357.2068454901.invoke(Unknown Source:-1)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
      
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
      at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.findAll(Unknown Source:-1)
```

I am using,
spring version 5.3.21
spring-boot version 2.7.0

Comment: Hi, could you provide more details? Does `MyInterface` definition compile?
I can't see the `ID` corresponding to the one from `Repository<T, ID>`.
What are the imports used in this class? Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do you autowire the RepositoryImpl instance? is it by RepositoryImpl or by the interface (MyInterface) ?

Comment: @kasptom I am trying to create a simple reproducible, but till now no luck. I will update you as soon as I have a reproducible

Comment: @JayamalJayamaha  it is by MyInterface

Answer (score 0):

hence you are autowiring by the interface, you need to add @Qulifire annotation top of @Autowire annotation or you need to autorwire by actually implemented class. please refer this to use @Qualifire annotation

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation